# How can I change colors of components when the mouse is pressed in a JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, setbackground, mouse-listeners

I am coding a piano in java using rectangles from the java.awt.graphics library.  I am using a mouselistener to play the sound of each individual key when the mouse clicks a certain area on the JFrame.

How would I add a shape to the panel upon clicking, repaint, then repaint the keyboard back over top when the user releases the mouse?

Comment: I actually meant to say JFrame. I apologize.

Comment: Paste us some code if you want: http://pastie.org

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels whether it's AWT or Swing has very little significance in this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry for the miscommunication, I forgot to include how I was creating shapes in my JFrame. I have posted code below in response to paranoid-android's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding JLabels to a JPanel that uses GridLayout. Give each JLabel a MouseListener and either swap ImageIcons on mousePress/mouseRelease or change the JLabel's background with press and release. If you go the latter route, you'll want to make sure that the JLabels opaque property is set to true so that the background colors show.

Then for the black keys, you can add the above JPanel to a JLayeredPane and on top of this, add another JPanel that holds the black keys that function in the same way.

Also, you'll want to take care to "play" any notes in a background thread, such as can be obtained with a SwingWorker so as not to tie up the Swing event thread and completely freeze your program.

Answer (score 2):

Consider solution: [source](http://pastie.org/3339017)

It might not be exactly what you're after, but it might give you an idea of how to approach your problem. It took me a long time to figure out how to use `JLayeredPane` *without* setting a null layout, but in the end this was the best I could come up with. Also, assumed some naming conventions for your sound files. :p

Comment: The problem with this is that I created the shapes by utilizing Graphics g from paintComponent using the code: `g.fillRect()`  Is there anyway to reference a specific shape?

Comment: I see. Tell you what, paste me some code and I'll take a look. http://pastie.org :)

Comment: http://pastie.org/3338408

I took out the black keys to make it a little easier to read. Excuse lack of elegance, I'm trying something totally out of my league here!

Comment: Totally understandable. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @user1: You're missing some code as the posted code won't compile.

Comment: I forgot to include all abstract methods for the MouseListener. Here's an updated version that should compile http://pastie.org/3338467